# installing python packages on production system(windows) without internet access and no internal pypi server

Tags: python, python-3.5, windows-server-2012, pypi, pycrypto

Is there a way to install python packages on systems without internet access and no internal pypi server.
I have tried installing it on local machine and then moving the package from site-packages to target location but it does not works.
Any other options.

Thanks

Comment: have you try with a linux ISO in a pendrive? (if you are on linux, of course)

Comment: It is a windows server. Sorry I forget to mention it in my question. Edited the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way my friend, you need to download first the packages and dependency of them to a folder and use pip package manager with a requirements file  like this:
pip install --no-index --find-links=[file://] -r requirements.txt

and if you want to download all the packages first in one hit use this:

pip install --download  -r requirements.txt

for more read here:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages
@maverick

Comment: here you are @maverick, I hope this help you

Comment: I am able to build wheel on my local machine(windows 7 64bit) but when I am trying to install it on my target machine(windows server 2012R2 64bit) it is throwing error "not a supported wheel on this platform".
Python interpreter is same on both the machines(3.5 32 bit)

Comment: tell me something @maverick all the packages work fine in your windows 7 64bit? So whatever, obviously the building process is binding something to your 64bit platform and you are changing to a new one who has a 32bit python interpreter and a for some reason there is a bond to something you don't know, so I recommend you to make a requirements file, download the source package and go to your 2012R2 64bit and the more important thing try to use pip connecting to pypi to avoid future conflicts with the same architectural troubles

Comment: I had to use `pip download -r requirements.txt`. then `pip install {each library}.whl` in the server manually for each library

Comment: @AhmadDeel try this `pip install --no-index --find-links=[file://] -r requirements.txt`  to avoid installing each library manually, `[file://[` a path to the folder where are all the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I had the situation and the answer from Reidel helped me. In my case, I knew I just had one package to install (i.e: `pathlib`).

To get the package to transfer to the offline machine, you can as well go to `pypi.org` and download the package ( https://pypi.org/project/pathlib/#files in my case).

To install it on the offline machine, I entered :

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=DIR PACKAGE_FILE
```

Hope it will help.